# Given a dataframe, groupby followed by sum operation and create new columns per each category in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Starting from a dataframe `df` I would like to groupby and sum per each category in a specific column and create a new column per each category (see below example with desired output). As an example given the dataframe df

```
data = {"ID": ["111", "111","111" , "2A2","3B3","4C4","5D5","6E6",],
"category": ["A", "B", "A","A","B","B","C","C",],
"length": [1,2,4,1,2,2,1,3],}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to obtain the original dataframe df with the additional columns A, B ,C (one new column per each unique attribute in the column "category") grouped by "ID"

I've checked some similar answers so far but I could not solve the issue.

This is one approach that I've followed without getting the desired output:

```
grouped_multiple = df.groupby(['ID','material']).agg({'length': [np.sum, np.sum, np.sum]})
grouped_multiple.columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
grouped_multiple = grouped_multiple.reset_index()
print(grouped_multiple)
```

which outputs:

[image: Output]

However my desidered output would look like

```
    ID  category A B C
0   111   A      5 2 0
1   2A2   A      1 0 0
2   3B3   B      0 2 0
3   4C4   B      0 2 0
4   5D5   C      0 0 1
5   6E6   C      0 0 3
```

Every element in the category column is grouped by the ID and category and then summed, then the columns are created for every unique value in the category column.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
The solution is working correctly: There are three points which I'd like to extend. First transform on the fly the names of the new columns,

say

```
    ID  category Custom_name_A Custom_name_B Custom_name_C  
0   111   A          5               2           0
1   2A2   A          1               0           0
2   3B3   B          0               2           0
3   4C4   B          0               2           0
4   5D5   C          0               0           1
5   6E6   C          0               0           3
```

Second, if I have an additional column with some years/decade

```
data = {"ID": ["111", "111","111" , "2A2","3B3","4C4","5D5","6E6",],
"category": ["A", "B", "A","A","B","B","C","B",],
"date": ["2020", "2010","2010", "1990", "1990","2010","2020","1990"]
"length": [1,2,4,1,2,2,1,3],}
```

I would like to see the following desired output: (CN = custom name, meaning a whatever string I need)

[Example of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpoR0.png)

Lastly:
I would like that this output is reflected in the original dataframe (because there are other columns which are not used by I would like them to be in this final group by)
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Get your final desire output, here I am trying create two separate df and at the end try to merge both.

Here df refers your final data provided, which includes year.

DF1:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'category'])['length'].sum().unstack().fillna(0).rename('CN_{}'.format, axis=1)
df1
```

Output:

```
category    CN_A    CN_B    CN_C
ID          
111         5.0     2.0     0.0
2A2         1.0     0.0     0.0
3B3         0.0     2.0     0.0
4C4         0.0     2.0     0.0
5D5         0.0     0.0     1.0
6E6         0.0     3.0     0.0
```

DF2:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ID','category','date'])['length'].sum().unstack().fillna(0).reset_index('category').groupby(['ID','category'])['1990','2010','2020'].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
df2.columns = ['CN_{}'.format('_'.join(col)) for col in df2.columns.values]
df2
```

Concat:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Final Output:

```
      CN_A  CN_B    CN_C    CN_1990_A   CN_1990_B   CN_1990_C   CN_2010_A   CN_2010_B   CN_2010_C   CN_2020_A   CN_2020_B   CN_2020_C
ID                                              
111    5.0  2.0     0.0      0.0        0.0          0.0         4.0            2.0        0.0          1.0         0.0         0.0
2A2    1.0  0.0     0.0      1.0        0.0          0.0         0.0            0.0        0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my question! Can I ask a way to do the same thing for several columns? say I had a "category_2" and "category_3" column with other attributes. Is there a way to do it in a simple way? 
Also is there a way to rename the columns on the fly with a "category_A, category_B etc "? Thanks!

Comment: For best solution, can you please update your input data and desire output?

Comment: I've edited the question, let me know if something is not clear. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Diauro please check the update.

Comment: Please hit upvote button if you appreciate answer.

Comment: Thanks this looks like solved my issue! I believe as a new member I cannot upvote immediately but I got "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, a `pivot_table` should do the job -

```py
df.pivot_table(values="length", index="ID", columns="category", aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
category  A  B  C
ID               
111       5  2  0
2A2       1  0  0
3B3       0  2  0
4C4       0  2  0
5D5       0  0  1
6E6       0  0  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've edited my question to extend what I need. Thanks